# What is Big O of two loops?

Tags: big-o

```
k=1
for i = 1 to 1000
 for j = 1 to i
  k = (k+i-j) * (2+i+j)
```

Above is the code, and I think it is O(n) but I am not sure, what is Big O of this loop? Can anyone explain it?

Comment: How could it be `O(n)` when `n` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop is running 1000 times, but the inner loop is also running 1000 times, so it will run 1000 * 1000 times.  Or 1000^2 (squared).  Therefore the notation would be O(n^2).  I apologize I do not know how to print the symbol for squared.

Reference: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/